can i have help fixing this unexpected null value error
im trying to run a login page for my application and i am recieving an error message this
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#4ebc1]:
Unexpected null value.
The relevant error-causing widget was
i treied using getX and multiple null checkers to no
import 'package:uber_version_2/screens/login/widgets/country_mobile_widget.dart';
import 'package:uber_version_2/screens/login/widgets/intro_widget.dart';
import 'package:uber_version_2/screens/otp/otp_screen.dart';
import 'package:uber_version_2/utils/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:fl_country_code_picker/fl_country_code_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String routeName = "/LoginScreen";
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final countryPicker = const FlCountryCodePicker();

  CountryCode countryCode =
      const CountryCode(name: 'SouthAfrica', code: "ZAR", dialCode: "+27");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: AppColors.greenColor,
            body: GetBuilder<GetxController>(builder: (_) {
              return SizedBox(
                width: Get.width ?? 0,
                height: Get.height ?? 0,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      const IntroWidget(),
                      Container(
                        width: Get.width ?? 0,
                        height: Get.height - Get.height * 0.6 ?? 0,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                                topRight: Radius.circular(25))),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            const SizedBox(height: 15),
                            const Text("Sign in now"),
                            CountryMobileWidget(countryCode, () async {
                              final code = await countryPicker.showPicker(
                                  context: context);
                              if (code != null) countryCode = code;
                              setState(() {});
                            }, onSubmit),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            })) ??
        Text('property is null');
  }

  onSubmit(String? input) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, OTPScreen.routeName,
        arguments: countryCode.dialCode + input!);
  }
}


this the full error
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#f49c4]:
Unexpected null value.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
Scaffold Scaffold:file:///C:/Users/Nero/Desktop/snaptow/lib/screens/login/login_screen.dart:26:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 296:3       throw
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 606:18  nullCheck
packages/get/get_state_manager/src/simple/get_state.dart 134:40                   initState
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5748:55                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5593:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5642:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5333:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5599:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5593:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5642:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5333:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5599:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5593:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5642:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5333:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5599:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5593:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5642:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5333:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5599:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5593:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 7035:36                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 7047:32                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5642:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5333:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5599:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5593:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5642:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5780:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5333:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5599:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5771:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5593:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5642:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5780:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5333:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5599:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5771:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5593:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5642:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5333:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5599:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5593:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5642:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5780:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5333:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5599:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5771:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5593:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6900:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5642:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5333:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5599:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5593:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6900:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5642:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5780:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5333:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5599:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5771:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5593:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5642:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5780:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5333:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5599:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5771:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5593:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5642:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5333:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5599:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5593:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5642:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5333:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5599:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5593:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5642:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5333:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5599:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5593:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5642:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5780:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5333:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5599:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5771:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5593:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5642:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5333:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5599:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5593:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5642:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5780:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5333:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5599:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5771:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5593:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3963:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5642:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5780:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5333:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5599:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5771:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5593:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4468:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3957:20                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5642:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5780:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5333:7                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2693:14                               [_tryRebuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2752:11                               [_flushDirtyElements]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3048:17                               buildScope
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1162:9                                  drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 468:5                                 [_handlePersistentFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1397:7                                [_invokeFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1318:9                                handleDrawFrame
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1040:9                                
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/isolate_helper.dart 48:11           internalCallback
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

can you share whole error

thie error code has been added above

GetBuilder(builder: (_) {  this itself causing the issue, so GetxController is not initialized or is null
